# How to sort a Highscore-ArrayList by points in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

How can I sort my ArrayList "highscoreList" by Points (highest first)

Here is a Highscore

```
public class Highscore {
  private String name;
  private int points;
  private Date date;
```

Here my List

```
ArrayList<Highscore> highscoreList;
```

Comment: Collections.sort using anonymous Comparator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `Collections.sort()` and override its `compare()` method:

```
Collections.sort(highscoreList, new Comparator<>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Highscore h1,Highscore h2) {
        return h2.getPoints() - h1.getPoints();
    }
});
```

The body of `compare()` method says how the instances of `Highscore` class would be compared. Assuming the `points` is the main and the only criteria, use them with getters.

This sorts in the descending order since you use `h2.getPoints() - h1.getPoints()`. To achieve the ascending order, just change the body of `compare()` method to: `h1.getPoints() - h2.getPoints()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Collections.sort` method has an optional `Comparator` variable:

```
Collections.sort(highscoreList, new Comparator<Highscore>(){
                     public int compare(Highscore h1,Highscore h2){
                           // Write your logic here.
                     }});
```

Of course, you can write an actual class that implements the Comparator, the above is just a shorthand.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you added  a return statement in the `Comparator` implementation